# Encrypt / Hide controller and action name from the url

Tags: php, url, encryption, yii

In my yii web application, I want to hide or encrypt the controller and action name in the url for security purpose. 
In my config/main.php,

```
 'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'rules' => array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

Now url is,

```
http://localhost/webschool/index.php/core/student/create
```

I want change this url to,

```
http://localhost/webschool/
```

or

```
http://localhost/webschool/uUG32376HJBDwg2366Gh_308
```

Please help me

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Dou read this before asking? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#faking-url-suffix

Comment: [You don't want to encrypt URL parameters](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php).

Comment: I tried, but can't solve my problem. I don't know how to change my urlmanager.  Please help me.

Comment: have you tried my proposal?

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own [**custom-url-rule-class**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-custom-url-rule-classes), for example:

```
class CustomUrlRule extends CBaseUrlRule
{
    public function createUrl($manager,$route,$params,$ampersand)
    {
        if ($route==='core/student/create')
        {
            // here use your own encryption logic
            return base64_encode($route);
        }
        return false;  // this rule does not apply
    }

    public function parseUrl($manager,$request,$pathInfo,$rawPathInfo)
    {
        // here use your own decryption logic
        $decoded = base64_decode($pathInfo);
        if ($decoded==='core/student/create') {
            return $decoded;
        }
        return false;  // this rule does not apply
    }
}
```

then declare it in the UrlManager section of your config:

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'rules' => array(
        // my custom rule (first one)
        array(
            'class' => 'application.components.CustomUrlRule',
            'connectionID' => 'db',  // if necessary for your logic
        ),
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```